# Not getting correct count of NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I could not able to get the actual count of object after setting it to the dictionary.
I  am having a structure pointer pEvent which i have put up in myData(NSData object).and I am storing this NSData into the dictionary.

```
[m_cAppIdMap setObject:myData forKey:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedShort:wTimerIds]];
int no = [m_cAppIdMap count];
NSLog(@"The no of entries in array is:%d",no);
```

Comment: is m_cAppIdMap an array or an mutable dictionary? (As an aside the `m_` for iVars isn't Cocoa-like)

Comment: @Abizern:Yeah m_cAppIdMap is a mutable dictionary.

Comment: Stick a breakpoint on the line - make sure that `myData` and the key are real objects. Also check the dictionary in the debugger to see whether that has any key-value pairs. Try adding another log: `NSLog(@"My dictionary is %@", m-cAppIdMap);` and see what you get. When you say you aren't getting the correct count - what are you getting? Is anything showing up in the debugger?

Comment: @Abizern:Its printing me a null value.Its not adding the key and value pair onto the dictionary and the dictionary is empty.

Comment: @Abizem:I made a mistake.I didnt intialise the NSMutableArray so is that error.Now i'm getting the correct value.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use int no = [m_cAppIdMap.allKeys count];

Comment: I tried as you told me to do.But i could not get the correct count value.

Comment: If the dictionary isn't able to return a `count` getting an array of the keys and counting that isn't going to work either, because if it had keys, it would have values, and it would then have a count.